# Javascript custom index accessor

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In c# you can create a custom indexer like so

```
public object this[string name]
    {

    }
```

I'm working with a javascript widget library which has a widget that takes an aray of objects as a property called labels like so

```
new  Thingy({
      labels: [{value:1, text:"my label"},[{value:2, text:"my next label"}]
      });
```

The problem is that you have to plan ahead to know exactly what all the values are that will need a label. For instance, in the example above, i know that the labels will be for values 1 and 2. But if I don't know what the values might be, i would like to be able to dynamicly create the text based on the value it tries to access

so when the library internally tries to access:

```
this.labels[n].text
```

I would like this.labels[n] to do something like

```
function(n){return {text: "label for " + n};}
```

Is this possible within the bounds of the javascript language?

Answer (score 1):

You can get [es6 proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies) in latest Chrome and write a handler like in C#, but it won't be compatible with older browsers.

Meanwhile I suggest putting a `getLabel()` method on a `Thingy.prototype`.