# How can you reference a custom data structure as if it were an array?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript custom index accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905787/javascript-custom-index-accessor)

If I were to write, say, a doubly-linked list object in Javascript, is there a way to reference this new list in a fashion like an array?

For instance, if I wanted the value of node 5, I'd like to query

```
newLinkedList[5]
```

instead of doing what I've been doing, which is something like

```
newLinkedList.getNode(5)
```

Basically, is there a way to "pretty up" references to custom data structures, or do you have to do it as a custom function each time?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in Javascript are really just objects with special handling for numerical properties. You can accomplish the same thing yourself, but currently Javascript doesn't provide a simple mechanism for transparent two-way accessing of those indices; you'll have to handle adding and deleting objects with named methods, but you can still benefit from reading them with array-like indexing.

Here's an example of a simple custom "Arrayish" object:

```
var ll_array = {};

ll_array.length = 0;

ll_array.addNode = function (newNode) {
    this[this.length] = newNode;
    this.length++;
};

ll_array.addNode('Foo');
ll_array.addNode('Bar');
console.log('Length: ' + ll_array.length);
console.log(ll_array);
console.log(ll_array[0]);
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/rbmsJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method of traversing the list, then assigning each item in the traversal to an array element, is the first thing that comes to mind:

Pretend you have a LinkedList object. Let's also presume there are methods for iterating the list called Head, and Next. Now, caveat being that this is entirely untested, you could create a prototype toArray() method in a manner such as:

```
LinkedList.prototype.toArray() = function () {   var array={};
                                                 var currentItem = list.head; 
                                                 while (currentItem!=null){
                                                     array.addNode(currentItem);
                                                     currentItem=currentItem.Next;
                                                 }
                                                 return array;
                                              }
```

Obviously this must allow for other presumed functions, but the idea is to traverse the linked list, and put a reference to each element in an array, and return it. Hope that helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

1. objects are saved in a double-linked list.
2. you know the getNode(int n) method to get n-th element.

there are no way to allow you get the n-th element with array style, [n]. because linked lists are not arrays, the elements in a linked list are linked to each other, this data structure is different from ordinary array or JavaScript style array:named property.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays ARE double linked lists without the links. To traverse right you simply increment the index, to traverse left you decrement the index.

You could write yourself a set of functions to perform the basic list operations and still have the facility of using simple indexing to reach any aribtrary element.